# play audio is not working in cordova

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0

```
<audio controls>

  <source src="/storage/emulated/0/h.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

here is the html code . Its not working . Please help me resolve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

This question gets asked about every year. It has to do with licensing on certain devices.

Try a plugin like [this](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio).

Or the official [media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media)

---

> The Media object provides the ability to record and play back audio files on a device.

`var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);`

> Note: The current implementation does not adhere to a W3C specification for media capture, and is provided for convenience only. A future implementation will adhere to the latest W3C specification and may deprecate the current APIs.

*Parameters*

- src: A URI containing the audio content. (DOMString)
- mediaSuccess: (Optional) The callback that is invoked after a Media object has completed the current play/record or stop action. (Function)
- mediaError: (Optional) The callback that is invoked if there was an error. (Function)
- mediaStatus: (Optional) The callback that is invoked to indicate status changes. (Function)

*Methods*

- media.getCurrentPosition: Returns the current position within an audio file.
- media.getDuration: Returns the duration of an audio file.
- media.play: Start or resume playing audio file.
- media.pause: Pause playing audio file.
- media.release: Releases the underlying OS'es audio resources.
- media.seekTo: Moves the position within the audio file.
- media.startRecord: Start recording audio file.
- media.stopRecord: Stop recording audio file.
- media.stop: Stop playing audio file.

Comment: I changed audio link in index.js file to /storage/emulated/0/h.mp3. but its not working .